# Add new rows to existing column of excel in python

Tags: python, excel

[image]

I want to add new records every week to this existing file without creating a new one.

For example, Next I want to add record on date 6/13/2016

Randy->(13,23,13)

Shaw->(13,15,13)

and many such entries next two months. How do I do that? I am beginner so having trouble to put it in syntax.

I could do only this much

```
import xlrd

#Opening the excel file
file_location= "C:/Users/agodgh1a/Desktop/Apurva/EPSON.xlsx"
workbook= xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xlrd
```

is for reading operations only. Since you want perform a write operation use
    xlwt 
python module.

Refer to xlwt docs for the same

Answer (score 2):

The lib you're using looks like it only reads, not edits.  Here's an example in `openpyxl`:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# create the file
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append([1, 2, 3])
wb.save("sample.xlsx")

# re-open and append
wb = load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
ws.append([4, 5, 6])
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Run that and you'll have a file `sample.xlsx` with both rows.